# Require ip 127.0.0.1 works sometimes and sometimes' it won't

Tags: apache, localhost, mod-auth

I have a very simple `.htaccess` file:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted

    # require localhost
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</RequireAll>
```

and it works... sometimes!

Sometimes, it will throw me a 403, and the `error.log` explains:

> [client ::1:65443] AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Why won't it match that local client to the `Require ip 127.0.0.1` rule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out, Apache 2.4's [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) matches the IP **exactly**. If you have multiple IP addresses aliasing `localhost`, you need to list all of them (or use a special alias, if one exists, as explained below).

In this particular case, the `error.log` entry reveals it all: The client connected through the [IPv6](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Internet/ipv6_ipv4_difference.html) interface (ip == ::1). That needs to be white-listed as well:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted

    # require localhost
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
        Require ip ::1
    </RequireAny>
</RequireAll>
```

Any suggestions as to whether there is a simpler/safer method to get this done, are very welcome!

**Update**

As [Helge Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234152/helge-klein) suggests, [`Require local`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal) is a more concise alternative:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted

    # require localhost
    Require local
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: Use "Require local" instead of listing IP addresses. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html for details.

Comment: Why do you need `Require all granted`? If you want to restrict to local, simply `Require local` would be sufficient, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the difference as my local config does not have the <RequireAll> and instead just puts everything into the <Directory> and just having Require local in there seems to be denying access for all the machines that are not local host. There is a catch however as Require local will not only allow access from localhost/127.0.0.1, but also the current IP of your computer in the network. This seems to be the main different with just just allowing the 127.0.0.1. Maybe this comment will save someone time on debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require ip ::1
```

Comment: This seems like a legitimate answer, but please add an *explanation* why it works, so we can all learn! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The **Require all granted** is the equivalent to:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

from earlier Apache versions, which open the site to everyone.  If your intention is to block the site to everyone, except certain IPs, you should start with a:

```
Require all denied
```

You can find more info here: [Upgrading to 2.4 from 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use .htaccess since I have Apache installed on my workstation, and have full access to the http.conf file.  But for a site like phpmyadmin where I want to limit where people log from, I have this:

```
Require all denied
Require ip 127.0.0.1
```

First line denies access to everyone, including my own workstation.
Second line adds my workstation localhost ip to the list of only allowed connections.

No **RequireAll** or **RequireAny** tags.  Again in .htaccess those tags may be needed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that 1) You are suggesting exactly what I have already tried and 2) You can just edit your other answer, you do not have to post more than one answer and 3) Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26699007/2228771) which already solved this particular problem.